# Shrink my screen for beamer output

Tags: windows, gratis, desktop-client, display, screen-sharing

In our company we use laptops with beamers in conference rooms and the screen setup is always a real mess. Unlike a few years ago, the resolution is not a problem any more. Most of our beamers can handle Full HD. However, it's the aspect ratio and the limited zoom that screws up things nowadays.

It's hard to explain in words, so I have created the following mockup of our problem:

[image: Beamer mess]

As you can see, the picture overlaps the edges of the silver screen. This typically messes up important things on the left side (like the start menu, also TreeViews are often there) and on the right side (scroll bars).

I promise that all the hardware possibilities are already exhausted, so I need a software solution. I expect it to do the following

- do not modify the physical screen resolution
- "reserve" a customizable amount of pixels on the left side, right side and top, like e.g. the Windows task bar does when it's locked (amount may differ on each side)
- prevent the mouse cursor from moving onto a reserved region
- the color of the reserved region should be black
- I don't really care about the Windows start menu, but if that could be affected as well, that would be even better

As a result, windows that are maximized should fit nicely on the silver screen.

In the following I have highlighted the reserved regions in blue.

[image: Expected result]